# Extract Class From Out Parameters

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, resharper

I have a method with `out` parameters like:

```
void Do(int anInput, out List<string> items, out int count)
{
   /* some code */
}
```

Now I want to transform that signature so that the out parameters are replaced by an object that is returned by that method like:

```
DoResult Do(int anInput)
{
   /* some code */
   return new DoResult{Items=TODO, Count=TODO};
}

class DoResult {
    public List<string> Items;
    public int Count;
}
```

Is there a refactoring for such a transformation in Visual Studio 2010 or ReSharper 7?

I know the ReSharper refactoring *Extract Class From Parameters*. But it seems it doesn't help me for `out` parameters.

*Update:* Daniel A. White's answer is very good for .Net 4.0. Is there a solution for .Net 3.5? Generation of a *Tuple* is also ok.

Comment: Do you really need this to be automated? How many places are you going to have to change? It should be fairly easy to do manually.

Comment: It would propably be a seldom used feature. But I'm lazy. :-)  I got the method with 2 `out` parameters by ReSharper's _Extract Method_ refactoring.

Comment: But how much work would it be for you to do the refactoring yourself right now, compared with working to find an automated solution?

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you want? Do you want to help? Do you want that I delete my question. Of course I asked because I think I can save time in future.

Comment: It just seems like such a relatively obscure case that a) it's unlikely to help many people; b) it's unlikely to help you much in the future either; c) it's unlikely to have been fully implemented in tools, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet c) JetBrains added this feature to ReSharper. See link in Daniel A. White's answer.

Comment: For Tuple, but not for an arbitrary class. And I still suspect you'd have been better off doing it manually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this refactoring in their documentation. It changes it to a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) but it should at least get you started.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Transform_Out_Parameters.html

From there, you can do Change Signature.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatly I cannot use that refactoring because it is only possible to transform *one* `out` parameter. I think this is so because I have a .NET 3.5 solution. (I added the .net3.5 tag now.)